# How to make "posting comment and replying " section in website with either PHP or Javascript.?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am in the middle of building my personal website. I feel that adding the section for "posting users comments and replies" will be nice idea to make my site a bit advance.

I don't want any users email-varification. They can just comment or reply post by submitting their names and email id.

Now which language is good to make that? I have worked with javaScript, jquery and php little bit. And finally please give an instruction or hints how to make that by using any of those language?

Comment: PHP, jQuery and javascript will do. But you also need a database.

Comment: disqus. no need to re-invent the wheel

Comment: You can use any programming language you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you should use `HTML` / `PHP` / `JavaScript (jQuery)`

Start by doing a regular form-element with your desired fields (for example firstname, email and message).

The next step (if you want it like this) is to set up the `database` (or txt-file... or whatever kind of storage engine you wanna use).

For a basic database-table you can take these fields:

```
id | firstname | email     |  message | 
1    John        john@doe.de  hi
```

So, everytime someone fills up the form, you insert the record to the database. Of course you can expand the table with fields like `published` (for example, you want to approve the posts first). This is up to you.

For this case, you should have a look at `mysql-connect` or something similiar, depending on what you wanna use (PDO, mysqli...) hard to tell if you are not giving any information.

To read the complete list of comments, you just `query` the table. Something like

```
$comments = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM my_comments);
```

As mentioned, have a look the the mysql-functions. It is really not hard.

Why i mentioned `jQuery`: If you want to do some client-side validation, you can check the inputs.

- is there a name?
- Is the comment at least 10 chars long
- Is the e-mail address in a valid form

...completly up to you, as always.

Then you can decide if you want to realize everything with `ajax` or a post-request with PHP and the form and reload the page to get the results.